# How to group two charts in one row of a window using extjs?

Tags: extjs

I have four charts in a window. They are displayed one after another in the one column. How can I have two columns, each containing two charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    width: 600,
    height: 500,
    title: 'Line Chart',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'column',
    items:[{
        height: 500,
        columnWidth:.5,
        items:[{
            height:250,
            layout:'fit',    
            items:createChart()
        },{
            height:250,
            layout:'fit',    
            items:createChart()
        }]
    },{
        height: 500,
        columnWidth:.5,
        items:[{
            height:250,
            layout:'fit',    
            items:createChart()
        },{
            height:250,
            layout:'fit',    
            items:createChart()
        }]
    }]
});
```

rest of the example: http://jsfiddle.net/fc8wQ/